# Could someone tell me the purpose of Inner classes and if iterator pattens should or a good idea to use inner classes?

Tags: java

Could someone tell me what the purpose of inner classes are? Also when designing the iterator pattern do we have to use inner classes? Would it be better to use inner classes?

Comment: Is this homework related? If so, please add the homework tag.

Comment: related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912520/why-bother-to-write-an-iterator-like-this

Comment: No its a question out of interest and for knowledge i guess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wikipedia has a [good article about the inner class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_class).

You don't need to use the inner classes for the [iterator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator_pattern):

```
import java.util.*; 
public class BitSetIterator implements Iterator<Boolean> { 
    private final BitSet bitset; 
    private int index;

    public BitSetIterator(BitSet bitset) { 
        this.bitset = bitset; 
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {   
        return index < bitset.length(); 
    } 

    public Boolean next() { 
        if (index >= bitset.length()) { 
            throw new NoSuchElementException(); 
        } 
        boolean b = bitset.get(index++); 
        return new Boolean(b); 
    } 

    public void remove() { 
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

An inner class is a class which can't survive without the class where it is definied in. In other words, if a class can't survive without a "parent" class, then it should be better an inner class of it. Some (if not most) iterators are definied as inner classes, because they are coupled to the current instance of the parent class and needs to have direct access to it. So needs for example the `ListIterator` implementation (which is declared as an inner class) as returned by `List#iterator()` direct access to the `get()` method of the current instance of the `List`.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to implement an interface as a part of your business logic but don't want it to be publicly available as a part of your classes contract inner classes allow you to do this.

On the whole since Java needs objects for everything they're quite often useful for things like listeners in UI programming where you need to listen to a bunch of buttons or other inputs, you can add an anonymous inner class to each of the inputs rather than having to put a whole lot of if then elses between the a single implementation of the listener for the buttons or whatever.

And no you don't have to use them for anything.